# Transchoice and yaml in Symfony

Tags: symfony, translation

I'm convinced of the yml translation files in Symfony. The strings are well structured.

My question is simple: is the following chaining in the plural string valid? And if the answer is yes, how to do that?

```
product:
    list:
        plural: "{0} product.list.none|{1} product.list.one|]1,19] product.list.lower20|[20,Inf[ product.list.larger20"
        none: There is no product
        one: There is one product
        lower20: There are %count% products
        larger20: There are many products
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, please try to clarify your question

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear:
I'd like to have one 'plural' string which is then parsed. For better structuring I'd prefer it like written above. but it does not work this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
product:
    list:
        plural: "{0} There is no product|{1} There is one product|]1,19] There are %count% products|[20,Inf[ There are many products"
```

Comment: And how in this case you can use different languages?

Comment: One language by yml file (messages.en.yml, messages.fr.yml, messages.it.yml ...)
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#component-translation-pluralization

Comment: I think that chaining of translation doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, It looks OK, sorry. Then just add this explanation and documentation link to your answer.